# Error: export 'control' (imported as 'L') was not found in '@raruto/leaflet-elevation' (module has no exports)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, leaflet

I have a angular application and need to use the custom leaflet package:
https://github.com/Raruto/leaflet-elevation

I am trying to use this in my application. I install it like so:

npm i @raruto/leaflet-elevation

and then at the top of my page imported it like so:
import * as L from '@raruto/leaflet-elevation';

```
    this.map =  L.map("map").setView([0.0, 0.0], 1);
    let googleRoadMap = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({
      type: 'roadmap'
    });

    googleRoadMap.addTo(this.map);
    L.control.elevation(elevation_options).addTo(this.map);
```

However I get the following error:

```
Error: export 'control' (imported as 'L') was not found in '@raruto/leaflet-elevation' (module has no exports)

Error: export 'map' (imported as 'L') was not found in '@raruto/leaflet-elevation' (module has no exports)

Error: export 'gridLayer' (imported as 'L') was not found in '@raruto/leaflet-elevation' (module has no exports)

 Error: export 'control' (imported as 'L') was not found in '@raruto/leaflet-elevation' (module has no exports)
```

I am new to JS and Angular etc I have come from PHP :)
I am wondering how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `import * as L` part is for the Leaflet base library.

Then depending on the plugin, you generally just have to import it for side effect, or you may have to import an explicit object as well.

In the case of `@raruto/leaflet-elevation` plugin, it looks like it is the former case, so you just have to do:

```
import * as L from "leaflet";
import "@raruto/leaflet-elevation";

this.map = L.map("map").setView([0.0, 0.0], 1);

L.control.elevation(elevation_options).addTo(this.map); // TS will warn here
```

Unfortunately, it looks like there is no TypeScript definition available for this `@raruto/leaflet-elevation` package.
So TS will not know what `L.control.elevation` is.
You can use a quick and dirty workaround:

```
(L.control as any).elevation(/* etc. */);
```

See https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.TileLayer.Fallback/issues/11 for further details and options.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, (as any) removed the error. However a new error now has appeared 
 Line 2288 - Msg: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module 'http://localhost/../src/handlers/distance.js'
    Error: Cannot find module 'http://localhost/../src/handlers/distance.js'

Comment: Seems like you try loading your app code as an ES module in the browser, instead of bundling it. Without further details on your setup, it is almost impossible to debug. Consider sharing a live reproduction example of your issue, e.g. using CodeSandbox or StackBlitz.