# Error: export 'Draw' (imported as 'L') was not found in 'leaflet'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet

These are my packages:

```
"@types/leaflet": "^1.8.0",
"@types/leaflet-draw": "^1.0.5",
"leaflet-canvas-markers": "^1.0.7",
"leaflet": "^1.9.1",
"leaflet-draw": "^1.0.4",
```

These are my imports a the top of my Angular service file:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-canvas-markers';
import 'leaflet-draw';
```

In **Angular 13** (*Typescript 4.6.4*) it was ok, but now I'm moving to **Angular 14** (*Typescript 4.7.4*) and I'm getting this error:

```
Error: export 'Draw' (imported as 'L') was not found in 'leaflet' (possible exports: ...)
```

I've got the same behavior with "canvasMarker" npm library.

```
Error: export 'canvasMarker' (imported as 'L') was not found in 'leaflet' (possible exports: ...)
```

The code that raise the error within my Angular service is:

```
const leafletDrawPolyline = new L.Draw.Polyline(map, options);
```

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72234621/error-export-control-imported-as-l-was-not-found-in-raruto-leaflet-elev), I tried in the following without success:

```
const leafletDrawPolyline = new (L.Draw as any).Polyline(map, options);
```

I understand it's a kind of import issue at Typescript level, but I don't know how to solve. Any suggestion?

Comment: Changing  target in tsconfig.json to ES6 doesn't work (actually is es2015)

Comment: You are not using @asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet, right?

Comment: this issue is not with @asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet, I also tried with this library, and the errors are the same but much more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue in leaflet 1.9.1. There is a bug report here: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/8521.
For now you can fix the version to leaflet 1.8.x by setting the version in package.json as `~1.8.0`.

Updated:
This is now fixed in [leaflet 1.9.2](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/releases/tag/v1.9.2) so setting leaflet to version `^1.9.2` should now work.

Comment: Thanks, the're saying that are going to release v1.9.2 today that will address this. Finger crossed.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I'm testing 1.9.2 and it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: With v1.9.2 no more errors, btw I had to add within angular.json the "allowedCommonJsDependencies" for "leaflet"